# MaterializeCSS autocomplete fill data from file

Tags: javascript, materialize

I want to fill data to MaterializeCSS autocomplete from a JSON file. My json file looks like this:

```
{
  "Escherichia coli(562)": "https://pax-db.org/images/species/511145.jpg",
  "Oryza sativa(4530)": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Rice_Plants_%28IRRI%29.jpg",
  "Zea mays(4577)": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Zea_mays_-_Köhler–s_Medizinal-Pflanzen-283.jpg"
}
```

The javascript code I wrote:

```
var organismData = {};
    $.getJSON('assets/data/organism_list_test.json', function(data) {
        $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            organismData[key] = "'" + val + "'";
        });
    }).done(function() {
        var organismElement = $('#organismName');
        console.log(organismData);
        organismElement.autocomplete({
            data: organismData
        });
    });
```

I want `organismData` to appear like this:

```
{
  "Escherichia coli(562)":'https://pax-db.org/images/species/511145.jpg',
  "Oryza sativa(4530)": 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/Rice_Plants_%28IRRI%29.jpg',
  "Zea mays(4577)": 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Zea_mays_-_Köhler–s_Medizinal-Pflanzen-283.jpg'
},
```

You can find an example here: https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html

Names get loaded, but nut images:

[image: Error]
[image]

What is wrong I am here to achieve the correct format here?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the current `organismData` you are getting?
Also, make sure that your `$.getJSON` works. It might be blocked by browser due to the Cross-Origin Request Blocked policy.

Comment: Yes your format seems correct. What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Arabidopsis thaliana(3702): "'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabidopsis_thaliana#/media/File:Arabidopsis_thaliana.jpg'"

Bemisia tabaci(7038): "'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Silverleaf_whitefly.jpg'"